# How to stop Windows Wallpaper from cutting?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, desktop-customization

Whenever I set a picture to 'Desktop Wallpaper', the picture always get cut and you can't see the whole picture.

How do I change the picture position?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the desktop wallpaper to either use Stretch or Fit to screen. This is done on the same screen where you change the background.

- Right Click Desktop
- Personalize
- Desktop Wallpaper
- Picture Position

[image: Change Background Picture Position]